# [8 is not a valid coordinate or range - Microsoft Excel Python

Tags: python, excel, indexing, range

I have this function to put the date on an excel spreadsheet. However everytime I run it I get a coordinate error. I've tried debugging it but haven't been able to figure out the source of the problem. Would anyone be able to help me?

Function:

```
def addDate():
# Get and format date
date = datetime.today().strftime('X%m/X%d')
date = date.replace('X0', 'X').replace('X', '')
# character number for "B"
cellStartNum = ord('B')
# Flag boolean to exit loop
emptyDateCell = False

while not emptyDateCell:
    # Get Current cell location
    currentCell = str(chr(cellStartNum)) + '8'
    # If the date is already there, then you do not need to add another column
    if ws[currentCell] == date:
        break
    else:
        # # If cell is not empty, move over one cell horizontally
        if ws[currentCell] != '':
            cellStartNum = cellStartNum + 1
        else:
            # If cell is empty, write the date
            ws[currentCell] = date
            ws[currentCell].font = Font(bold=True)
            emptyDateCell = True
```

Error:

> [8 is not a valid coordinate or range

Comment: What do you expect to happen after `cellStartNum` reaches `ord('Z')`? Note that `ord('Z') + 1 == ord('[')`

Comment: **Please provide the entire error message, as well as a [mcve].**